# How to add the characters "st" ,"nd", "th" next to the day e.g 1st, 2nd, 28th

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to setup a date format but from docs and other websites i checked there is no mention on how to make this type of format

2**nd** of January 2017

```
Date.tomorrow.strftime("%e %B %Y")
```

will give

**28 January 2017**

how can i make it

28th of January 2017 ?

is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the exact format you mentioned :

```
d = Date.tomorrow
d.strftime("#{d.day.ordinalize} of %B %Y")
=> "28th of January 2017"
```

If you use it multiple times, you could [define](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Date.html#method-i-to_formatted_s) :

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:my_date_format] = lambda { |date| date.strftime("#{date.day.ordinalize} of %B %Y") }
```

in `config/initializers/date_formats.rb` (create it if not already present)

You can then call :

```
Date.tomorrow.to_s(:my_date_format)
=> "28th of January 2017"
```

Answer (score 5):

In Rails [Time](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html), [Date](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html) and [DateTime](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html) have `to_formatted_s` methods:

In your case you're looking for [Date#`to_formatted_s`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-to_formatted_s):

```
Date.tomorrow.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal)
#=> "January 28th, 2017"
```

Comment: @AndreyDeineko thanks for letting me know of this `.to_formatted_s` function - i will keep it in mind :)